# Git rebase doesn't move past file deleted by us

Tags: git, github

I am trying to rebase my `master` based on `upstream`.

1. When I rebase, I get a `CONFLICT (modify/delete): file.txt deleted in HEAD and modified in <version>`.
2. `git status` says `deleted by us: file.txt`
3. I `git rm file.txt`. I get `needs merge`
4. but now `git status` says `all conflicts fixed`
5. when I `git rebase --skip` I get back to (1.)

git version 2.10.1

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you run `git rebase --continue`on step 5?

Comment: When rebasing depending on the type of conflict, and whether subsequent commits rely on the conflicted change, you may have to resolve the conflict many times during a rebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a `git rebase --skip` will nullify any changes you made during the rebase. You are almost correct with your workflow, you only need to do the following after doing a `git rm file.txt`:

- `git add .` - to make sure all your changes have been added to staging
- `git status` - for a sanity check
- `git rebase --continue` - this will save all the changes that you did during the rebase.

Comment: When I add `git add .` and then continue with `git rebase --continue` I get `New doc structure \ No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?` If I go for `git rebase --skip` instead, it throws me into a loop.

Comment: Can you try with a `rm file.txt` instead of `git rm file.txt`?

Comment: `git add` in fact allowed me to proceed, I guess I can mop this up later.